# AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner cannot be resolved

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to run tests with powermockito however I cannot run the test because I get the following error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files ClientTest.java /ClientServerChat/test/tests    line 1  Java Problem
```

I have added the following jars to the project:

```
1.mockito-all-1.10.19.jar
2.powermock-api-mockito-1.6.3.jar
3.powermock-core-1.6.3.jar
4.powermock-module-junit4-1.6.3.jar
```

Am I missing  a dependency or something else should be done?

Here is the test file : https://pastebin.com/Dv7wtDTp

Answer (score 0):

That class is part of the [`powermock-module-junit4-common`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4-common) JAR.